# Чергування і та и у власних уменах

Tags: переклад, росіянізм, правопис, власні-назви

Мене цікавить чи чергуються -і та -и в українській. Я, як людина, що нещодавно перейшла на українську в своєму житті виступаю за те, щоб не перекладати рос. власні імена на українську. Одже моє ім'я Михайло, часто скорочують до Міша. Але знайшовши словник-довідник Скрипника від НАН України такої форми не має. Є Миша, Мишко, Мись і т.д. І якщо я не помиляюсь щонайменше в сучасному правописі ці голосні не чергуються. Але щойно подивився відео від Твоя Підпільна Гуманітарка, де наголошувалось:  "і та и в укр. мові близькі, та в різних стандартах і однакових позиціях часто бувають взаємозамінні." Я розумію що вірити словам будь-кого в інтернеті хибно, але автор начебто розбирається в темі. То ж хто знає, або добре розуміється на українській, підкажіть. Тому що як мені здається "Міша" — росіянізм.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я [теж] не пригадую такого явища як чергування *и ~ і*. Можуть хіба що бути випадки, що подібні на чергування, але такими не є.

**Перший**, це де, коли такий процес відбував ся, *і* злилося з *и*, що згодом так і залишилося. З найвідоміших [випадків](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D1%82%D1%8C#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4_%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%C2%AB%D0%B8%C2%BB): *діти*, але *дит-ина*; *сід-ниця*, але *сид-іти* — зазвичай це з ненаголошеним *ѣ* і наступною наголошеною голосною, особливо *и*. Також це помітно при [старих запозиках](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D1%82%D1%8C#%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81) як *мѣнута*, *фѣґура* ітд, де згодом можна було отримати наприклад *минута* або *мінута*. І коли мова про запозики по реліґійній тематицї, куди і входить наприклад *Михайло*, то тут якраз за сучасним звичаєм все [записується](https://files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf#page=160) через *и*:

> За традицією з **и** пишемо також слова грецького походження, що усталилися в церковному вжитку: *диякон, єпúскоп, єпитúмія, єпитрахúль, мúро, мúтра, митрополúт, християнство* тощо.

Однак в говірках це цілком може бути через *і*, тобто *Міхаїл* [і похідні], а не *Михаїл*. Тому якщо кажете *Михайло*, то скоріш за всього це *Миша*, *Мишко*, *Мись* ітд.

Загалом, сумнівне [правило девʼятки](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8), що скоріш за всього польського походження, підпадає під цей випадок теж: *дизель*, але *Дізель*.

**Другий**, це ґраматичний поділ на мʼякі, тверді і мішані ґрупи. Однак це вже геть інша проблема, що радше залежна від абетки, пор.: [*нема*] *вод-и*, *лял-і* і *ляль-и*.